# Disconnecting unwanted remote access

Tags: networking, security, sudo, remote

If someone is remotely connected to my single ARM board computer with Debian 32-bit OS, (example: thru hijacking the browser), which connects through a firewall on a separate Orange Pi board, and I run **shutdown**, I have been told that the remote users/ hackers will “immediately” be disconnected from my computer and  they can't see what I do before shutdown completes in the next 60 seconds.

1) In order for the first premise to ring true, do I need to be in admin “#”, for example:  **# shutdown**  ?
2) After reading more, it seems that by NOT including “-h” (shutdown -h now) it does not actually halt the system; it still allows the administrator to remain logged in as root. If I omit the **-h**, will the remote hackers still be disconnected immediately with just **shutdown now**?
3) If I type **shutdown +90**, will the remote hackers be disconnected immediately, and then for the next 90 minutes as well?

Comment: Do a fresh install of Fedora 30 Gnome or KDE, It's the most secure from the box https://getfedora.org/ OR https://spins.fedoraproject.org/en/kde/

Comment: That means new Linux os for your computer

Comment: Thanks. The person who told me that actually writes for stackexchange :) I don't know if I should mention his name here, but he is an expert's expert. It's important realize that the 'malware' is not permanently on the OS, and that it disappears when I shutdown/ restart the desktop. My experience with this and these hackers is that once I restart the desktop, they are gone. But I am still curious about my 3 questions. Thanks.

Comment: As others have already tried to tell you... reinstall your system!

Comment: Reinstalling the OS would be of no value. Once I logged into a certain account that is programmed with malware to hijack my browser, the same thing would happen again. "As I have already tried to tell you" - the malware is NOT permanently on the OS. My questions are not only about the browser hijacking, but also regarding how to safely network if you suspect someone may be on your computer.

Comment: Even though I haven't had my 3 questions answered, thanks to all who have replied thus far.